# Is there a Python MySQL library which implements the new MySQL v8+ TRUE async feature?

Tags: python, mysql, asynchronous

For MySQL v8 and up, it is now possible to perform actual asynchronous operations.  The official documentation covers how to do this in C:

C API Asynchronous Interface

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/c-api/8.0/en/c-api-asynchronous-interface.html

There are a collection of "async" MySQL Python libraries, but I'm not sure any are really completely non-blocking.  They look to be "pseudo async", and especially when I don't see any indications that MySQL v8 or above is required to be paired with them.

I'm sure I can roll this C mechanism into Python via an extension, in a worse case scenario.  I was just hoping maybe someone else already did the work for me!